# How to calculate 95% CI for a Z test in Base R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I was given a small set of data and was instructed for the first portion of the question on my assignment to develop a user-defined function for a 1-sample z test, since base R does not a function for it. This is what I have.

```
Scores = c(116, 128, 125, 119, 89, 99, 105, 116, 118)

alpha  = 0.05
x_bar  = mean(Scores)
mu_0   = 100
sigma  = 15
n      = length(Scores)

# 1-sample z-test is not available in base R. Let's build an user-defined function for it.

onesample.ztest = function(x_bar, mu_0, sigma, n){
   one.z.stat       = (x_bar - mu_0) / (sigma/sqrt(n))
   
   pvalue_twosided  = 2 * pnorm(-abs(one.z.stat), mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=TRUE)
   pvalue_less      = pnorm(one.z.stat, mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=TRUE)
   pvalue_greater   = 1 - pnorm(one.z.stat, mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=TRUE)
   
   output = list(
                 paste("one.z.stat =",       round(one.z.stat, 4)), 
                 paste("pvalue_twosided =",  round(pvalue_twosided, 4)),  
                 paste("pvalue_less =",      round(pvalue_less, 4)), 
                 paste("pvalue_greater =",   round(pvalue_greater, 4))
                )
   return(output)
  }
```

This is what the output is

```
onesample.ztest(x_bar=x_bar, mu_0=mu_0, sigma=sigma, n=n)
## [[1]]
## [1] "one.z.stat = 2.5556"
## [[2]]
## [1] "pvalue_twosided = 0.0106"
## [[3]]
## [1] "pvalue_less = 0.9947"
## [[4]]
## [1] "pvalue_greater = 0.0053"
# onesample.ztest(x_bar=112.777777777778, mu_0=100, sigma=15, n=9)
# onesample.ztest(x_bar, mu_0, sigma, n)
# onesample.ztest(112.777777777778, 100, 15, 9)
```

This all works very well; however, I need to now tweak the code to calculate and return the 95% CI within the code above. This is an assignment, hence why I am instructed to do this in base R and in this particular way. Does anyone have any ideas of how I could add code to calculate and output the CI?

Comment: The 95% CI is usually just your mean +/-(z stat * 1.96).

Comment: @deschen, I think your formula is wrong: you should replace `z stat` by `s.e. = sigma/sqrt(n)`.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I didn‘t pay enough attention, yes, Basically SE *1.96, not zstat.

Comment: `qnorm(0.975)` would be slightly better than 1.96

Answer (score 0):

For a Z test the 95% confidence interval can be calculated with

```
mu_0 - qnorm(0.975) * sigma/sqt(n)
mu_0 + qnorm(0.975) * sigma/sqt(n)
```